# Как отобразить картинку в ToolTip которая загружена в image на которую наведен курсор? - C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

У меня есть динамически созданные Image, и при наведении курсора на Image мне нужно в tooltip вывести картинку этого Image. Код программы приведен ниже, но он не работает, я думаю что проблема в Binding-привязке. Буду рад любой помощи =)

```
<Window.Resorces>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsControl>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource,Mode=OneWay}" Width="120" Height="120">
                                <Image.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip>
                                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource,Mode=OneWay}" Width="480" Height="480"/>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </Image.ToolTip>
                            </Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Эээ... А для чего вам в тултипе `ItemsControl`? Да ещё и пустой, без Item'ов.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю, то вы слегка вывернули наизнанку свою задачу: определяете стиль для `Image`, в котором в `ToolTip` кладёте список изображений, к которым и должен применяться стиль, который вы определяете. Должно быть на самом деле что-то такое:

```
<Window x:Class="Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ImageViewModels}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                       Width="120"
                       Height="120">
                    <Image.ToolTip>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"
                               Width="480"
                               Height="480" />
                    </Image.ToolTip>
                </Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Где у объекта в `DataContext` окна есть свойство `ImageViewModels` - список моделей представления изображений, а у каждой модели представления изображения есть свойство `ImageSource` - путь к изображению.

Comment: Написал так же, только в <Window.Resources>, но все ровно не работает. Ничего не выводит. Если вывести к примеру, Source, любого Image, то ссылка не совсем корректная, может быть из-за этого не работает.

Comment: file///C:/MyDir/1.jpg - во такого вида ссылка получается в Source.

Comment: А должна быть вроде как просто C:/MyDir/1.jpg

Comment: @Marshall, что и зачем вы написали в window.resources?

Comment: У меня много динамически созданных Image. И мне нужно что бы при наведении на каждый из них выводить изображение Image. Для этого я написал этот код  в  window.resources.

Comment: @Marshall, этот код и выводит список динамически созданных Image. Это не стиль,это и есть содержимое окна. Как вы создаёте и выводите свои Image?

Comment: ну все так же, все как полагается, так же регистрирую им имена 'this.RegisterName(Imagesty[i].Name, Imagesty[i]);' . Проверял ссылку, этих Image, все так же как и у Image добавленных обычным способом.